# How to get the maximum of a rolling sequence in R

Tags: r, max, quantmod

I have a large data base in R, containing all the closing prices of different stocks, and i want to get the maximum of each when compared to the previous rows of the stock, kinda like this:

```
Data max
1     1
2     2
1     2
3     3
5     5
6     6
3     6
2     6
1     6
4     6
5     6
7     7 
3     7
```

I have tried using rollmax, but, since it requires a width, at some point it just stops working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `cummax`

```
df1$max <- cummax(df1$Data)
```

-output

```
> df1
   Data max
1     1   1
2     2   2
3     1   2
4     3   3
5     5   5
6     6   6
7     3   6
8     2   6
9     1   6
10    4   6
11    5   6
12    7   7
13    3   7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Data = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
5L, 7L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```